# Check a null value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following date in a dataframe:

```
date1               date2               date3
--------------------------------------------------------
16/07/2021 13:32    16/07/2021 14:25    26/07/2021 16:49
null                15/07/2021 15:14    null
31/10/2021 07:02    31/10/2021 07:11    12/11/2021 14:57
09/11/2021 16:35    10/11/2021 09:02    10/12/2021 18:45
```

I want to check if a date value is 'null' or not. So I tried the following methods but anyone seem to works correctly.

```
>>> print(df['date1'][0])
16/07/2021 13:32

>>> print(df['date1'][1])
nan

>>> print(df['date1'][1] == 'null')
False

>>> print(df['date1'][1] == 'nan')
False

>>> print(df['date1'][1] == 'Nan')
False

>>> print(df['date1'][1] is None)
False
```

Anyone has some hint to solve the problem?

Comment: `df[df["date1"].isna()]` presumably

Answer (score 0):

try with
[pandas.DataFrame.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas.DataFrame.isna)